# Retrieve List of "hibernate proxy objects" with "Spring Data Jpa query"

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Can I somehow retrieve a list of **Hibernate proxy objects** with **Spring Data Jpa query?**

I have object ids from request, and I don’t want to retrieve them (because there are many OneToOne relations in entity), but I want to **retrieve their proxies which will contain their ids** ( I need this for relation ). I want something like `Hibernate findOne()` or `getOne()` but for list result.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Mmmh I don't understand the question. You basically don't want a complete object?

Comment: What is doing getOne() ? Its getting proxy object without loading it entirely right? So I want the same but for list. Smth like findAll(QUser.user.userType.eq(“manager”)) with querydsl.

Comment: @LppEdd And I want findAll result to be a list of proxy objects.

Comment: Start again. Your requirements are unclear.  It seems to me you either want to return  *either* (a) a list of IDs only or, (b) a list of objects but without their associations being set. There are different possible solutions depending on your requirements so read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and then clarify what it is you want to do.

Comment: Have you tried the solution I proposed in my answer?

Comment: I just used EntityManager getReference() for making list and set it as relation.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your questions right you want to do something like this:

**Geo-spatial repository queries** (does not require @Query annotation)

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, String>
List<Person> findByLocationNear(String location, Integer distance);
List<Person> findByCity(String city);
}
```

However You may also use JQL Query Methods in you repository

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person t WHERE p.name =?1 AND p.location=?2 ") 
List<Person> findPersonByLocation(String fName, String location);
```

Also, you may use [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: I think it will load objects of list entirely but not proxies right?

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is using an `EntityManager` instance.

```
entityManager.getReference(YourClass.class, id);
```

Being that this method accepts only a single ID, you'd need to write a custom `SQL` query (using `HQL` or native `SQL`) to retrieve **only the IDs** of the needed objects.

Having a `List<T> ids`, you can than

```
final List<YourClass> proxyValues = 
         ids.stream()
            .map(id -> entityManager.getReference(YourClass.class, id))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Speaking about performance, this is perfectly fine, as the database access would be done a single time, retrieving a small amount of data.